# Is it possible to submit regex to google web searches?

Tags: regex, google-search

Is it at all possible to submit any form of a regex to google web search? Even a wildcard character would be interesting tool. Or is it literal strings and options **only**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google supports wildcards, actually!

No regular expressions, unfortunately, I doubt even google have the server capacity to perform regex searches on their databases. The wildcard (*) is a fairly powerful tool regardless.

Comment: Good answer, I figured they wouldn't be capable of handling regex. But the wildcard is good news.